# JRebel's taking too much time to update

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, java-ee-6, jrebel

I've got an Maven-WAR-packaged JavaEE6 project here which has an EJB service layer and a JSF2-based web layer.

Every time I try to update source by JRebel plugin (Netbeans 8.1) it takes almost the same time than a full redeployment (considering even a Glassfish restart).

Does anyone here faced this kind of problem? Any tips, guidelines for a quick solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NetBeans, the automatic deployment of the changes is automatically enabled. Make sure that the checkbox is unset if you want to use JRebel. Chances are that this is the reason why updating the app takes time.

Right click on the project -> Properties -> Run -> unset "Deploy on Save"

[image: Deploy on Save]

If this is not the case, shoot the email at support@zeroturnaround.com - they should help.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the answer. Well, I've just checked the "Deploy on Save" option on my project properties and it's already unchecked.

Comment: Then I'd encourage you to report the slowness to support@zeroturnaround.com They can ask more additional details and could probably help resolving the issue.